# Padded Text on Image

Tags: html, css

I apologize for this very noobish question, but I couldn't find a similar one on here.

So my **html** looks something like this:

```
<div id="headerone">
   <h1>How To <br> Bench Press</h1>
</div>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
    #headerone {
            background: url(http://www.prodality.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Workout.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            height:630px;   
            padding-top: 100px;
            padding-left: 600px;
        }
        #headerone h1 {
            background-color: black;
            display: inline;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: white;
            line-height: 50px;
            padding: 10px;
            box-decoration-break: clone;
            -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
```

I want to have a background hero image with the width of 100%, and I'm trying to achieve this effect:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wbaapq

On top of my image, but if I make width of the background image 100% it would change the width of the text as well.

With the code above, everything is where it should be, but when I make the browser window smaller, the position of the text seems to be absolute and doesn't move with the rest of my code. Is there a better way to do this, or am I inputing something wrong? Anything I need to add? Do let me know, thank you!

Best Regards,
Omgummy

Comment: Yes, you need to add @media breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use @media breakpoints [demo](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/KwGrza)

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .padded-multiline {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: My text still seems to not move when I minimize my browser window?

Comment: It looks like it works fine, I copied it word for word, now the text moves with the browser, but the background image size changed and doesn't go 100% with the browser.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.stronglifts.com/
The image with the text on it.

Comment: I've updated the code, please take a look http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/KwGrza

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to debug it! I found a solution.